# What is wrong with my localhost:5000/users url in this node.js project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url

I'm using node.js to build a REST CRUD, and to check if my urls are working i'm trying to get a "Hello1" message when I  acess the url "localhost:5000/users", but all I get when I acess it is Cannot GET /users. I really don't know what's wrong with my code, because i'm following exactly what the tutorial says. Does anybody know what's going on?

users.js file:

```
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();


router.get('/' , (req,res) => {
    res.send("Hello1");
});

export default router;
```

//////////////////////////////////////
index.js file

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import usersRoutes from './routes/users.js';


const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send("hello");
})

app.get('/users', usersRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server running on localhost:"+PORT));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
app.get('/users', usersRoutes);
```

You should use:

```
app.use('/users', usersRoutes);
```